# Objective: understanding File permissions

Tags: command-line, permissions, scripts

I want to write a shell script that takes two arguments: username(usr) and filename(fname), then resolve and show permissions of the given user on the given file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check with `ls -lh` whether the owner of the file is `$usr`. If `$usr` is the owner, he has the permissions what `ls` lists for the owner.
- Use the `groups $usr` command to get the groups which the user belongs to. Check with `ls -lh` whether the file's group owner is one of the group of the `$usr`. If it is so, then the `$usr` has the permissions what `ls` lists for the group.
- Check the permission for "other", `$usr` (and in fact everyone) have those permissions what `ls` lists for "other".

Then just combine (bitwise OR) all the permission what `$usr` got from the above 3.

Comment: Thansk alot,but can you write the code to me,because linux is a new system for me and i have a homework i have to be delivered after two days,thank you so much again ^_^

Comment: @FaresJoha The point of the homework is to learn something. You won't learn anything if you just hand in a script that somebody writes for you.